# unused arguments with function expected

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I analysis `newdata$E<-expected(newdata$population, newdata$DBD, 4)` then i get message:

```
Error in expected
(dbd_temporary$population, dbd_temporary$DBD, 4) :
  unused arguments (dbd_temporary$DBD, 4)
```

notes: newdata$E is a new column to combine newdata$population and newdata$DBD. in newdata has no variable/column named E

Comment: What package is the function `expected()` from?

Comment: Read the documentation or the code of the `expected` function. It only has one argument but you are passing three arguments.